# Two synchronized statements. How do they work?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to run one method with the synchronized statement within another.

**MyClass**

```
public class MyClass {

    private Object lockObject = new Object();

    public void testFirst() {
        synchronized (lockObject) {
            System.out.println("Entered testFirst() sync");
            testSecond();
            System.out.println("Leaving testFirst() sync");
        }
    }

    private void testSecond() {
        synchronized (lockObject) {
            System.out.println("Entered testSecond() sync");
        }
    }

}
```

**Main**

```
package com.replanet;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.testFirst();
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Entered testFirst() sync
Entered testSecond() sync
Leaving testFirst() sync
```

I expected another output.

```
Entered testFirst() sync
Leaving testFirst() sync
Entered testSecond() sync
```

Why will not `testSecond()` wait till `testFirst()` finishes its job?

Comment: +1 for ICP reference.

Comment: you are clearely not understanding locks. 
please read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: @fredcrs, thank you. I will read the documentation. I am reading the book called "Java Concurrency Guidelines" by Fred Long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are seeing this seemingly strange behaviour because each lock is associated with the **thread** that requests it and once you have the lock you keep it until you unlock.

In your code you are obtaining the same lock twice so the second attempt succeeds immediately because you already have it.

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) for reference:

> When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all **other threads** that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object.

Comment: Just adding: If it not would have worked this way this method would dead-lock on itself

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon, `each lock is associated with the thread that requests`. Not with the thread but with the object, isn't it?

Comment: @RedPlanet - Pretty sure it's the `Thread` that holds the lock on the `Object`. Perhaps I have misunderstood you/it.

Comment: @RedPlanet - Found the reference [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) - it says *When one **thread** is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other **threads** that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object.*

Answer (score 3):

Since to enter the first `synchronized` section you must have the lock of object `lockObject`, when you arrive at the second `synchronized` section you still have it so it continues. When running `testFirst`,  the `synchronized` block in `testSecond` changes nothing.

Answer (score 2):

A few things to keep in mind:

- `synchronized` blocks are reentrant: when you hold a lock via a `synchronized` statement, you can enter another `synchronized` block using the same monitor - in your case, nothing prevents you from calling `testSecond` from `testFirst`
- now imagine that the 2 methods used different monitors, you would still get the same output because no other thread would be holding the lock of `testSecond`
- *IF* the 2 methods used two different locks *AND* another thread held the lock used in `testSecond` the execution of `testFirst` would not skip the call to `testSecond` and move on, it would block until the lock becomes available again

Answer (score 1):

Beause **testSecond()** is associated with **testFirst()**

control flow exactly like below:-

```
System.out.println("Entered testFirst() sync");
       System.out.println("Entered testSecond() sync");
System.out.println("Leaving testFirst() sync");
```

Answer (score 1):

Synchronization is built around an internal entity known as the intrinsic lock or monitor lock.
Every object has an intrinsic lock associated with it. By convention, a thread that needs exclusive and consistent access to an object's fields has to acquire the object's intrinsic lock before accessing them, and then release the intrinsic lock when it's done with them. A thread is said to own the intrinsic lock between the time it has acquired the lock and released the lock. As long as a thread owns an intrinsic lock, no other thread can acquire the same lock. The other thread will block when it attempts to acquire the lock.

so your thread is owner of lockObject so it can enter to all code inside the block with lockObject

Answer (score 0):

I edited the code I had posted. And the synchronized statement makes sense, doesn't it?

**MyClass**

```
public class MyClass {

    private Object lockObject = new Object();

    public void testFirst() throws InterruptedException {
        // Here is something that should not be synchronized 
        synchronized (lockObject) {
            System.out.println("testFirst() is about to fall asleep. "
                    + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("testFirst() woke up. " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }

}
```

**MyThread**

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    private MyClass myClass;

    public MyThread(MyClass myClass) {
        this.myClass = myClass;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            myClass.testFirst();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            interrupt();
        }
        super.run();
    }

}
```

**Usage**

```
package com.replanet;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        MyThread mThread = new MyThread(myClass);
        MyThread anotherThread = new MyThread(myClass);
        mThread.start();
        anotherThread.start();
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
testFirst() is about to fall asleep. Thread-0
testFirst() woke up. Thread-0
testFirst() is about to fall asleep. Thread-1
testFirst() woke up. Thread-1
```